# Why does the browser trigger a refetch of values in useQuery from TanStack when it is refocused?

Tags: react-query, tanstack, tanstackreact-query

I'm using the useQuery hook from the React Query library in my React application to fetch data from my server. However, I've noticed that whenever I switch away from the browser tab and then come back to it, the useQuery hook triggers a refetch of the data.

I would like to understand why this is happening and how I can prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because react-query refetches stale queries when a window focus event happens, and per default, all queries are considered stale.

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/window-focus-refetching

The best way to work with this and similar situations is to specify an appropriate `staleTime` for your resource.